# StackView returns the ex-height in viewDidLayoutSubviews

Tags: swift, uistackview, viewdidlayoutsubviews

So I have a `scrollView`, inside that `scrollView` is a `stackView` that contains every `views` in the screen.

The problem is my `stackView` has many hide-able `views` so I need to adjust my `containsVieww's height` base on my `stackView's height`

my psuedo code should be like this :

```
 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    print(stackView.bounds.height)
    // do logic to change contentView size here
 }
func setupView(){
    scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.backgroundColor = .white
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
    
    scrollView.addSubview(stackView)
    stackView.setArrangedSubView(views: [label1, label 2, label 3, label 4, ..., label n]
    [label1, label 2, label 3].isHidden = true
}

func onHitButton(){
   if isHidden {
   [label1, label 2, label 3].isHidden = false
   isHidden = false
  } else {
   [label1, label 2, label 3].isHidden = true
   isHidden = true
  }
  print(stackView.bounds.height) // still return the ex height
}
```

Here is the problem:

On first `init`, my `[label1,2,3].isHidden = true`, my `stackViewHeight` is `500`

When my `onHitButton` is called, my `[label1,2,3].isHidden = false`, my `stackViewHeight` is still `500` but the screen displays correctly, those `labels` are visible now and my `stackView` is stretched. And of course my `scrollView` is not displays correctly.

Then I hit my `onHitButton` again, those `labels` are hidden, my `stackView` is shrink on screen but the `stackViewHeight` returned `850`?

It's supposed to be the other way around.

I also tried to `print` the `height` on another `button` call and it return the right `height`? Seem like `viewDidLayoutSubviews` called too early.

To sum it up: `stackView` return the height before it resize it self

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use auto-layout to constrain the stack view to the scroll view's **Content Layout Guide**:

```
    scrollView.addSubview(stackView)
    
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    // reference to scrollView's Content Layout Guide
    let cGuide = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide

    // reference to scrollView's Frame Layout Guide
    let fGuide = scrollView.frameLayoutGuide
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        
        // constrain stackView to scrollView's Content Layout Guide
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cGuide.topAnchor),
        stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cGuide.leadingAnchor),
        stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cGuide.trailingAnchor),
        stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cGuide.bottomAnchor),
        
        // constrain stackView's Width to scrollView's Frame Layout Guide
        stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fGuide.widthAnchor),
        
    ])
```

This will completely avoid the need to ever set `.contentSize` -- it will all be handled by auto-layout.

Comment: why would you give leading and trailing anchor why there is already a widthAnchor? Beside that one, everything works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: One more minor problem that I found is it seems like I can't adjust bottomAnchor constant, the bottom of my last view in stackView is alway at view.BottomAnchor without any space. I tried to give constant in both stackView bottomAnchor and scrollView bottomAnchor but it didn't work .

But giving `topAnchor constant` work. Strange

Comment: *Leading / Trailing / Width Anchors* ... that's the way scroll views work. Leading and Trailing + Width determines the **Horizontal** scrolling size, Top and Bottom + Height determines the **Vertical** scrolling size. Here, we use the stack view content (the arranged subviews) to determine its height. Comment-out the Width constraint line, and see what you get. Then try setting the Constant on the Width constraint to 100, or 500, or 1000 and see what you get.

Comment: *"my last view in stackView is alway at view.BottomAnchor without any space"* ... Do you mean you want some "empty space" after the bottom of the stack view? If so, give a negative value for the bottom anchor's constant. For example: `stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -100.0),`